# AWS SNS Flexibility to Publish to Subset of Topic's Subscribers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

Here is the model I want to build:
Unlimited topics (I know the AWS limit is currently 3000)
Unlimited subscribers per topic (AWS SNS documentation does not state a limit)

Each subscriber will have a different schedule that they wish to receive SMS or email messages.

If I have a topic with 10 subscribers where 5 want morning messages and 5 want evening messages.  The schedules can be changed and will be administered by a web app (utilizing the API) by an administrator so building one topic per schedule is not the ideal solution and the variations would chew up a lot of the 3000 topics.

Answer (score 3):

SNS does not support the ability to publish to a subset of topic subscribers, other than when using its Android/iOS push notification capability, which is neither email nor http nor sms, and is so different than everything else SNS does, I'm not entirely sure why Amazon didn't market it as an entirely different product.

> At this time, direct addressing is only supported for push notifications to iOS, Kindle, and Android endpoints
>
> <sup>http://aws.amazon.com/sns/faqs/#Does_SNS_support_direct_addressing_for_SMS_or_Email</sup>

The [documented limit](http://aws.amazon.com/sns/faqs/#How_many_subscribers_can_be_added_to_a_single_topic) for the number of subscribers to a single topic is 10,000.  This appears to be a hard limit; however, the limit of 3,000 topics per account is apparently not a hard limit, since there is a documented process for [requesting an increase](http://aws.amazon.com/sns/faqs/#Are_there_limits_to_the_number_of_topics_or_number_of_subscribers_per_topic) to that limit.

There's a big gap between 3,000 topics of 10,000 subscribers each and 10 subscribers split among 2 or 3 topics, but it still doesn't seem like SNS is the right platform for what you're trying to do -- limits or no limits -- because every time a subscriber is added to a topic, they have to confirm their subscription to that topic... so if whatever your admin does to manipulate topic subscribership will still result in [a confirmation message from "AWS Notifications"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SubscribeTopic.html) being sent to each subscriber from Amazon SNS requiring them to opt-in before subsequent messages can be delivered, and that's a process that would be have to be repeated if a subscriber wanted to change their delivery schedule (which means adding them to a new topic).  You can't programmatically skip this step.

Within AWS, [Simple Email Service](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/) seems like a more appropriate (and recipient-friendly, assuming your recipients are from the general public) platform based on what it seems like you're contemplating, with the logic of determining which recipients are associated with each message being determined by logic from your database... it doesn't have the same pricing structure, and it doesn't do SMS (though SMS through SNS seems pretty pricey at any rate), and unlike SNS, SES doesn't have a 256k limit per message.

That does put more of a burden on your application, since you'd have to send copies of the message to SES for each subscriber, but if outgoing bandwidth is an issue, an instance deployed inside EC2 could easily take care of replicating and transmitting the message to SES.  With SES, you also get [bounce and complaint notifications](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/faqs/#39) on your messages.

This is the approach I would take.

But then again, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The hard limit of 10K subscribers per topic has been lifted on 19 AUG 2014: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/sns-large-topics-and-mpns-auth-mode/

Comment: @Darius, thank you. I'll review and update as indicated.

Comment: Can i create multiple subscribers for a particular topic.Like say i have created a topic electronics and now i want to create Ac,Fan,refrigerator etc.. subscribers under a electronics topic.Is this possible??

Comment: @Learning, if I understand what you are asking, that's sort of the point of a "topic," to fan-out to multiple subscribers from a single publish event.

Comment: when i create a subscription to a particular topic with application protocol and i specify My mobile as an End point then does sns send confirmation notification to my mobile end point?